# URL Params and Security using Magento

Tags: php, security, magento, url, parameters

I am wondering how **secure it is** to have a URL(pointing to php file) that *accepts params*, and with these params can update collection items in a magento database and/or other commands etc.

Im thinking using this would not good practice for both PHP GET & Magento

Example would be...

Update Param (update product)

```
url/post.php?type=update&pro_id=2234&price=55&pro_name=New Name&another_param=etc...
```

Same would be for create, delete (Set via  type=delete....)

Obviously not having the URl over https is a first issue but what if i added extra params that have to match & exist admin config settings for the code to execute correctly (if not redirect or display error etc). Something like

```
admin_user=myadminname&admin_api_key=34654905098Huygvwef8738788fsdfj
```

and code would be

```
if(admin_name == admin_name_setting) {
if(admin_api_key == admin_api_key_setting) {

//Both Things match, so do some commands etc

}else{

 //Key dont match so kick user

}

}else{

 //Dont match so kick user & log

}
```

I know the various types of APIs exist for Magento (limited to default Magento Database Actions unless custom API coded), but my question is how logical and secure is it to use this kind of function(s) or would this be a big "NoNo" as it would be easily hackable and a direct access to database manipulation?

*Keep in mind i would have a custom admin setting to create/update a rewrite for the main URL as well..*

*And logging too if attempts to access the url with incorrect params (and correct params) to auto kick/ban user via IP*